# Cannot get Ajax script to work for PHP login page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am  have a problem when using Ajax to send data to a Mysql database without refreshing the page.

Can anyone please point out where I might have gone wrong? I placed an alert: `alert('it worked');` in the AJAX on success part of the script to see what happened. It also returns "it works".

(I have removed the validation part of script for ease of reference, but I do have it.)

I also  checked the values that were returned from the variable dataString:

```
email =a3&pass=a
```

I have no idea why it's not sending the values to the PHP page.

```
//START THE FUNCTION FOR THE SUBMISSION OF THE LOGIN FORM VIA AJAX 

$('form[name=loginForm]').submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#pass").val();

    var dataString = 'email =' + email + '&pass=' + password;

    //the html below is just used to test the values that are derived from the dataStirng. 
    $('#showerror').html( dataString  );

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cms/index.php?view=login",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            alert('it worked');
            //document.newMessage.newMessageContent.value = "";
        }
    });     
});  
//END THE FUNCTION FOR THE SUBMISSION OF THE LOGIN FORM VIA AJAX
```

Comment: dataString should be an object. { email : email, pass : password }

Comment: You can write echo "test"; in your ajax request page.As well as write success:function(html){alert(html);} and check it. If its alert test then you can send request perfectly. try this

Comment: @mark its not compulsory you have also pass url string like that

Comment: Post your ajax request page code so its help to find actual problem

Comment: Post your `PHP` code too

Comment: @Harry : this code should work.. even if nothing is `echo`-ed on php page.

Answer (score 0):

send data like:

```
{'email': email, 'pass': password}
```

***OR***

```
var dataString = 'email =' + email + '&pass=' + password;
                       ^--- remove this space
```

so it will

```
var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&pass=' + password;
```

`Space` is not allowed within query string. [See here the heading ***URL encoding***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: The `dataString` is sent as `data: dataString` in `$.ajax` so NOT removing that space will not make any difference as it will be treated as normal string